# glog verbose logging & Boost program options

Tags: c++, boost, glog

I am using `boost` `program options` in my code and trying to add verbose logging using `glog` (google logging library).

The problem is that `boost` captures the command line options and I can not use the `--v` flag for controlling the verbose logging. Is there a method for setting the `minloglevel` from the code? I failed locating a function or a macro for doing that programatically...

Comment: I don't know if these flags can be set programatically in the Google Logging library, but if it can then you just add those options yourself.

Comment: yes, I know I can add them myself, I am looking for a method for doing that programatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem and am managing to set glog flags in my main function as follows:

```
namespace po = boost::program_options;

int main(int ac, char **av) {
    po::options_description desc("...");
    desc.add_options()
    ("verbosity,v", po::value<int>(), "set verbose logging level, defaults to 0")
    ;

    po::variables_map vm;
    try{
        po::store(po::parse_command_line(ac, av, desc), vm);
        po::notify(vm);
    }
    catch (po::required_option& e){
        ...
    }
    ...
    if (vm.count("verbosity")){
        FLAGS_v = vm["verbosity"].as<int>();
    }
    else{
        FLAGS_v = 0;
    }
    google::InitGoogleLogging("...");
}
```

Comment: Perfect! I even prefer the short syntax:
`( "verbosity,v", po::value<int>( &FLAGS_v )->default_value(FLAGS_v), "set verbose logging level, defaults to 0")`

Comment: I didn't know that was possible, neat!

Answer (score 0):

I found one work around and one answer that should but doesn't work.
You can use the environment variable `GLOG_v` to set the verbosity level

(on linux)`GLOG_v=2 ./your_binary` This works well but is not ideal

I also found the not very well documented function `google::SetVLOGLevel(char*, int)` that is exactly what I was looking for, but unfortunately using it throws an exception.

Comment: You should probably have said "I also found the not very well documented function google::SetVLOGLevel(char*, int) that is exactly what I was looking for, but unfortunately using it throws an exception" in the question and then asked for someone to "solve" that. Preferrably with a SSCCE. There is probably a good reason why it fails at the time.