# Disable glog's "LOG(INFO)" logging

Tags: c++, glog

I'm trying to optimize my c++ program. It uses caffe.
When executing my program, caffe outputs around 1GB (!) of info logs every 15 mins. I suspect this impacts efficiency significantly. But I haven't found how to turn logging off. In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28345346/glog-verbose-logging-boost-program-options) someone suggested setting `FLAGS_v` manually.

With the following code I can disable `VLOG` logs by level, but `LOG(x)` logs are unaffected.

First lines in `main()`:

```
FLAGS_v = 1; //disables vlog(2), vlog(3), vlog(4)
VLOG(0) << "Verbose 0";
VLOG(1) << "Verbose 1";
VLOG(2) << "Verbose 2";
VLOG(3) << "Verbose 3";
VLOG(4) << "Verbose 4";
LOG(INFO) << "LOG(INFO)";
LOG(WARNING) << "LOG(WARNING)";
LOG(ERROR) << "LOG(ERROR)";
```

Output:

```
WARNING: Logging before InitGoogleLogging() is written to STDERR
I0523 19:06:51.484634 14115 main.cpp:381] Verbose 0
I0523 19:06:51.484699 14115 main.cpp:382] Verbose 1
I0523 19:06:51.484705 14115 main.cpp:386] LOG(INFO)
W0523 19:06:51.484710 14115 main.cpp:387] LOG(WARNING)
E0523 19:06:51.484715 14115 main.cpp:388] LOG(ERROR)
```

Is there another `flag` I'm unaware of? I'm thinking of commenting every `LOG(INFO)` line out, but I would like a more elegant solution. (I'd prefer a c++ solution over a command line flag solution).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This works in C++ source code.

```
google::InitGoogleLogging("XXX");
google::SetCommandLineOption("GLOG_minloglevel", "2");
```

Answer (score 10):

you need to set your environment variable

```
GLOG_minloglevel=2
```

then run your executable.

You can find more information [here](http://rpg.ifi.uzh.ch/docs/glog.html) (at the bottom of this page there is a section on stripping `LOG()`s from your code using a macro definition).

Comment: is there a way to do it from code instead of setting an environment variable? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to turn off log from code level, you can use this.

Just add below line in your c++ code at **src/caffe/net.cpp** in `Init` method and build caffe:

```
fLI::FLAGS_minloglevel=3;
```

Partial view of the function where this line should be added:

```
   template <typename Dtype>
    void Net<Dtype>::Init(const NetParameter& in_param) {

      fLI::FLAGS_minloglevel=3;


      // Set phase from the state.
      phase_ = in_param.state().phase();
      // Filter layers based on their include/exclude rules and
      // the current NetState.
      NetParameter filtered_param;
      FilterNet(in_param, &filtered_param);
      LOG(INFO) << "Initializing net from parameters: " << std::endl
                << filtered_param.DebugString();
      // Create a copy of filtered_param with splits added where necessary.
      NetParameter param;
      InsertSplits(filtered_param, &param);
      // Basically, build all the layers and set up their connections.
      name_ = param.name();

      .
      .
      .
      .
```

Set log level according to your necessity.

Comment: It was enough for me. Just had to include this line and recompile the libcaffe. Great!

Answer (score 2):

The environment variable "GLOG_minloglevel" will filter some log but they have been compile in your executable file. If you want to disable them during compiling time, define a macro:

"#define GOOGLE_STRIP_LOG 1"

This is the comment in logging.h:

```
111 // The global value of GOOGLE_STRIP_LOG. All the messages logged to             
112 // LOG(XXX) with severity less than GOOGLE_STRIP_LOG will not be displayed.     
113 // If it can be determined at compile time that the message will not be         
114 // printed, the statement will be compiled out.                                 
115 //                                                                              
116 // Example: to strip out all INFO and WARNING messages, use the value           
117 // of 2 below. To make an exception for WARNING messages from a single          
118 // file, add "#define GOOGLE_STRIP_LOG 1" to that file _before_ including       
119 // base/logging.h                                                               
120 #ifndef GOOGLE_STRIP_LOG                                                                                                                                                                                
121 #define GOOGLE_STRIP_LOG 0                                                      
122 #endif
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to answer of Qi Cai,
if there is a dependency on Gflags library, than remove "GLOG_".

```
google::SetCommandLineOption("minloglevel", "2");
```

Each levels matches to
INFO : 0
WARNING : 1 ...

Comment: Luckily for you, your post is NOT a comment. That would have been inappropriate, flagged as not an answer and removed in short order. You did however create an acceptable answer with reference to a different one (at least I am willing to see it that way). That is allowed. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

### glog version

> commit d4e8eb
> Date:   2021-03-02 09:59:36 +0100

```
#include <glog/logging.h>

FLAGS_minloglevel = 100;
```