# strip caffe's logging message from my own c++ program

Tags: c++, caffe, glog

I am making my own c++ classification program using caffe library.
I want to hide all logging messages during caffe's model initialization step.

According to [Disable glog's "LOG(INFO)" logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37397262/disable-glogs-loginfo-logging),
I could disable most of logs by setting environment variable

> GLOG_minloglevel=2

from command line.

But, What I really want is to remove all logs from the executable itself, so the user can not turn on the logs by resetting GLOG_minloglevel value.

I could find a way to strip glog's logging message on compile time from http://rpg.ifi.uzh.ch/docs/glog.html.
It says I can remove logs like this:

```
> #define GOOGLE_STRIP_LOG 1    // this must go before the #include!   
> #include <glog/logging.h>
```

Since my application uses caffe's c++ library, I needed to rebuild caffe library with adding following option `add_definitions(-DGOOGLE_STRIP_LOG=2)` to caffe's CMakeLists.txt.
The compile was successful, but when I ran my application with new caffe library, it stops with segmentation fault error during model initialization step. 
I could get a bit more detailed error message by running with gdb like this:

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>   __memcpy_sse2_unaligned () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memcpy-sse2-unaligned.S:153
>   153   ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memcpy-sse2-unaligned.S: No such file or directory

When I roll back to the original caffe library without `add_definitions(-DGOOGLE_STRIP_LOG=2)` in caffe's CMakeLists.txt, my application runs fine.

Can anyone give me a hint for solving this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Currious as to why you'd want to remove logging - couldn't it be useful at some point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider that google::LogToStderr() is described as: "Make it so that all log messages go only to stderr."  (see glog/logging.h).

So, whatever it's doing will probably give us a clue how we might disable logging to files.  It turns out its implementation is simply:

```
SetStderrLogging(0);            // thus everything is "also" logged to stderr
for ( int i = 0; i < NUM_SEVERITIES; ++i ) {
  SetLogDestination(i, "");     // "" turns off logging to a logfile
}
```

So, to disable logging to files, you need only SetLogDestination() to "", for all severities.

You'll probably also want to disable all logging to stderr (it seems to default to GLOG_ERROR).  This can be accomplished with addition of:

```
google::SetStderrLogging( google::NUM_SEVERITIES );
```

BTW, my rationale for doing this is that I want to redirect GLOG messages to a different logging framework already in use by the app.  I've found I can accomplish this by additionally calling google::AddLogSink(), with my own sink.